# NoClassDefFoundError org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor while using hibernate 5.1.0 with Spring 5.1.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

While using `Hibernate` `5.1.0` in `Spring` `5.1.3` I see `NoClassDefFoundError`

Error is reported for missing class `SharedSessionContractImplementor`. Which is valid because this was added in `Hibernate 5.2.0` However project is configured to use `5.1.0`.

Pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.1.0.Final</version>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
```

Context

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetBeanName" value="appHibernateProperties"/>
            <property name="propertyPath" value="hibernateProperties"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:hibernateComponentMappings.cfg.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<alias name="sessionFactory" alias="sessionFactoryReporting"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:577)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.xxx.xxx.dao.xxx$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43e03fc6.getResourceToExtensionMapForCategory(<generated>)
        at com.xx.xx.xx.xx.loadMappings(JuelSmpExtensionLoader.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor
        ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: then you need to add `Hibernate 5.2.0`

Comment: Can't upgrade to 5.2.0 because of a dependency from third party component

Comment: Perhaps you could rewrite that missing class into your project ?

Comment: Perhaps it will bring too many dependencies. When app was in 4.3 and hibernate 5.1 spring everything was fine. Now when spring is upgraded to 5.1.3 and hibernate is kept at 5.1 i see this issue.

Comment: AFAIK the minimal version of Hibernate for Spring Framework 5.1 is hibernate 5.2...  So either don't upgrade Spring or upgrade Hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

This was a problem with `HibernateTransactionManager` in `spring 5.1.3`
Which is fixed in `spring 5.1.4` as per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22089

So upgrading `spring to 5.1.4` will fix this issue.